# Syntax error from htaccess on a line unsure what is wrong with the line

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, hotlinking

HI all not too familiar with coding however. Trying to disable hotlinking from htacess as it is not enabled on cpanel. If my woocommerce sends a mail to a user all images are hotlink protected. Im trying to disable this but the error im getting on cpanel is

`AH00526: Syntax error on line 97 of /home/f6502669/public_html/.htaccess.cnzOkKh8bL2j8FntD1hdnZea5t8Ts25E: Header has too many arguments`

This is line 97 `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,E=HTTPS:1]`
underneath is content security policy.

Basically what needs fixing on Line 97 so that on cpanel i can take away the file extentions that were hotlink protected.

Comment: That error message doesn't sound as if it had anything to do directly with the shown RewriteRule, and much more as if it was concerning some `Header` directive, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header Can you show us the full .htaccess file, or if that's too big, at least a couple of lines before & after line 97?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind the csp had no " and ' two lines down this seems to of fixed the issue.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,E=HTTPS:1]
    Header set Content-Security-Policy: "default-src'
```